# Stripe Issues after transctions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have an issues on stripe. Customer create on stripe is successfully but after it payment status return to me pending from stripe side.

pending http://uat.ultravie.co.uk/webhook

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

To pay out users with Stripe you will need to collect some information about them for compliance purposes. You can read many more specifics of exactly what you need to collect here:

https://support.stripe.com/questions/What-is-the-process-for-verifying-managed

In this case the user needs the following in order to re-enable charges and transfers:

"legal_entity.address.city"

"legal_entity.address.line1"

"legal_entity.address.postal_code"

"legal_entity.address.state"

"legal_entity.dob.day"

"legal_entity.dob.month"

"legal_entity.dob.year"

"legal_entity.type"

"tos_acceptance.date"

"tos_acceptance.ip"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, your webhooks stay pending after payments. If yes, check that you set up an URL in `Account Settings > Webhooks`. Once your URL is set up in Stripe Dashboard, it should work if you are not working in localhost (you should see request on the URL you set up), you can either send a test webhook from the Stripe dashboard.

If you are working in localhost, you first need to create a tunnel to allow Stripe Webhooks to reach you. This can be achieve using a tool like `UltraHook` or `Ngrok`. Once you run one of these binaries, it will create a tunnel to their servers and provide you an URL that you can set in the Stripe Dashboard as written above. As soon as you set up the tunnel & the url, you can test the webhooks with a stripe test webhook from the dashboard and it should work.